# How to setup gitlab-ci job to re-use all branches job in a specific master only job?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working with Gitlab-CI and I am thinking about one job for all the branches which basically could be considered as some sort of unit tests and another job dedicated to the master branch which would for example copy and do some actual actions. The unit-tests job has to run on all the branches.

I am wondering whether the scripts can be overlapped, so that basically the all the branches job could be executed prior to the master one as a kind of validation.

The idea is to enforce two conditions available in the merge requests:

- Only allow merge requests to be merged if the pipeline succeeds
- Only allow merge requests to be merged if all discussions are resolved

I simplified a bit the `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follows:

```
job_all_branches:
  script:
    - unit-tests

job_master_branch:
  script:
    - copy-files
  only:
    - master
```

Of course, one could mention that we can copy and paste the unit-tests script from the all branches job into the scripts called in the job_master_branch, but I am wondering if there a way to avoid a redundant definition.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. You can use `except: master` on the unit-tests if you like.

Gitlab supports [requiring the build to pass before merging](https://gitlab.mercuria.met/help/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds#only-allow-merge-requests-to-be-merged-if-the-pipeline-succeeds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a solution, it was actually super easy, I just had to use stages...:
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages
- https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/29/the-basics-of-gitlab-ci/

Feel like a complete idiot that I haven't figured this out before.
Anyway here is below what I wanted to achieve:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./my-test-script.sh
  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - my
    - lovely
    - test
    - runner


deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./my-deploy-script.sh
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - my
    - lovely
    - deployment
    - runner
```

And they are therefore processed sequentially :)